# rails 3 and rubyzip 1.0.0 uninitialized constant Zip::ZipFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyzip

Im attempting to open a docx file and write back into it using rubyzip 1.0.0 and rails 3.

In my gemfile I have:

```
gem 'rubyzip'
```

and the code i'm running is;

```
module Look

  class Generator

    def initialize(item)
      doc   = Nokogiri::XML.parse(item.to_xml)
      xslt  = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read("<path_to_xslt_file>.xslt"))
      @outxml=xslt.transform(doc)
      zip = Zip::ZipFile.open("<path_to_docx_file>.docx")
      @outxml
    end

  end

end
```

While the @outxml is created correctly (I can manually add it to the docx file and see the results), I can't even begin with creating the zip file because of this...

```
uninitialized constant Zip::ZipFile
```

Having checked all the documentation and tried many combinations I'm still completely stumped.

Can anyone please tell me why this won't work?

Thanks.

Comment: Just figured this one out by checking the latest documentation. Seems v1.0.0 was only released today so everything I read was out of date. Anyway, the solution is to use Zip::File.open.

Comment: You might want to make that comment an actual answer and then choose it as the correct answer so people in the future can find it easily.

Comment: Yes. SO wouldn't let me add this as an answer until 8 hours had passed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just figured this one out by checking the latest documentation. Seems v1.0.0 was only released today so everything I read was out of date.

Anyway, the solution is to use

```
Zip::File.open
```